# return contour label positions

Tags: python, matplotlib

The reproducible example below shows nearly concentric contours; it captures something I'm trying to do with matplotlib for comparing a 2D analytical solution to a numerical method solution. Because the two solution have small differences, the contours do not plot on top of one another.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

delta = 0.025
x = numpy.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = numpy.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)
  
Z1 = numpy.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = numpy.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

Z2 = Z * 1.1

# adding labels to the line contours
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CS = ax.contour(X, Y, Z)
CS2 = ax.contour(X, Y, Z2)
ax.clabel(CS, inline=1, fmt='%1d', fontsize=10)
#ax.clabel(CS2, inline=True, fmt='%1d', fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Simplest default with labels')

plt.show()
```

Is there a way to return the position of where labels were added to CS so that a "blank patch" could be drawn on CS2?

Simply adding contour labels to `ax.clabel(CS2,...)` (uncomment the 3rd-to-last line) isn't quite what I would like to do. For example, in the plot below, generated by uncommenting the 3rd-to-ast line, the lower contour labels identified by "1" aren't near each other.  In the real-world problem, it would be preferrable to simply label 1 set of contours and add a blank spot nearby in the other set of contours.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to return the position of where labels were added to CS so that a "blank patch" could be drawn on CS2?

Yes. `ax.clabel()` returns the list of added labels, i.e `Text` instances ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.clabel.html)). You can get the position of each label by calling `.get_position()` ([see here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.get_position))

```py
labels = ax.clabel(CS2, inline=True, fmt='%1d', fontsize=10)
labels[0].get_position()
# > (0.8249999999999855, 0.8218697194205205)
```

It's not clear to me what you want to do with that, but once you have access to the labels, you can do pretty much anything (removing certain labels, re-positioning, adding a bounding box around it, etc...).

Here is an example of such manipulation

```py
# [...]

labels = ax.clabel(CS, inline=1, fmt='%1d', fontsize=10)

for label in labels:
    label.set_bbox(dict(facecolor="w",  pad=2, ec="none"))

# [...]
```

[image]

Comment: That nails it!  Thanks for the solution